# @Html.ActionLink to a <a href="@Url.Action()>

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html.actionlink, url.action

the doubt is this:
I have to use a `<a></a>`, because of the notation I'm using in all my app, I'm working in ASP.NET MVC. So, I have an `href="@Url.Action` with `class="btn btn-primary"`, a simple button as this:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Manage", "Account")" class="btn btn-primary text-right">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></span> Administrar 
</a>
```

**(That was an example of the estructure that I need)**

But now I have to convert this:

```
@Html.ActionLink(User.Identity.GetUserName(), "Manage", "Account",
routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Administrar" })
```

to that estructure. The fact is, I don't know where to put the `routevalues` and `User.Identity.GetUserName()`. I don't need the `htmlAttributes` neither the title.

Please help me and thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

For title, you just simple use `title="Administrar"`, so when you hover mouse on the button/link, it'll still show `Administrar` in tool-tip.

For Username, you will need `@` sign at the front.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Manage", "Account")" class="btn btn-primary text-right"
   title="Administrar">
  <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-left" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
  @User.Identity.GetUserName()
</a>
```

Another suggestion is not to use Bootstrap's glyphicon, because they won't be available in [next version](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/migration/#components) anymore. Instead, you might want to consider using [Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io/).

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Manage", "Account")" class="btn btn-primary text-right">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-left" aria-hidden="true"></span> 
   @User.Identity.GetUserName() 
</a>
```

`routevalues` will be next parameter in `Url.Action` method if you need it.

Like this:

```
Url.Action("Manage", "Account", new { id = 1 })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I suppose you have Html.Actionlink like bellow
  

     @Html.ActionLink("Home", "index", null, new  { @class = "btn btn-primary" })

all you need to do is to write it like this 

    <a class="brand" href="@Url.Action("index","Home")"> </a>

and you are done!
```